# How i can build corda project locally?

Tags: java, gradle, corda

I want to put all dependencies jars in a folder and try to use it again and again instead of making it download from internet everytime.
What should i do?

Comment: Go through this: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html

Answer (score 0):

Steps to build Corda is documented here: https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/building-corda.html

Answer (score 0):

1. I believe that Gradle downloads your dependencies only once (when you first open the project and click on `Import Gradle Project` pop-up); it will download a certain dependency again, if you change its version.
2. If you want to build your nodes and install all of the dependencies on them (i.e. place the jar files of your dependencies in their `cordapps` folder); then simply setup the dependencies for each node inside the `deployNodes` task in the root `build.gradle` file, then run the command `./gradlew deployNodes` which will create the folder structure (and install the dependencies) under `your-project/build/nodes/`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handcraft your node. 
Follow this link:-
docs.corda.net/corda-os/4.4/generating-a-node.html